# Spring - Tomcat Configuration - can not create a .war file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I created a new project in Spring Boot, but I have a problem with the Tomcat server configuration. I can not create a `.war` file to run this application.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Usually after creating a project immediately after pressing 'fix' I had to choose the .war patch, but here there is no such possibility.

Comment: A spring boot application does not need tomcat. It has an embedded application server. You only need to start your application. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

To run the Sprint Boot application, you do not need a Tomcat server, just need to find a class with an entry point and run it.

But if you still need a Tomcat server, here are two steps that I hope will help you.

First step:

[image: First step]

Second step:

[image: Second step]